# understanding lsof -i output with web browsing

Tags: linux, networking, lsof

I don't understand some output lsof command.

I try to run lsof -i on my home machine(debian linux) and what i obtain (showed one line; my browser chromium was running)

```
# lsof -i
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
chromium- 2379   brenta   70u  IPv4  45006      0t0  TCP brenta.local:44023->stackoverflow.com:www (ESTABLISHED)
```

the man page explains about column NAME:

```
the local and remote Internet addresses of a network file;
the local host name or IP number is followed by a colon (':'), the port,
``->'', and the two-part remote address.
```

I try to run this comman on the other machine (linux mint):

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox   2778   brenta  59u   IPv4 68476917      0t0  TCP NOT_MY_HOST:39812->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Why column NAME contains not my host, but the other machine in local network?

Comment: perhaps the name couldn't be resolved, what says `lsof -n -i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer given by user bersch in comment:
"the name couldn't be resolved"